# How can I restore squid's acls

Tags: linux, squid

Accidentally I deleted my acl file, which contained about 100 IPs.

Squid is still running at the moment. I didn't restart it. And now it works correctly, but if I restart it, it'll lose acl.

**Is there way to export current configuration?**

I have in `squid.conf`:

> ```
> acl restricted src "/etc/squid/acls/restricted"
> ```

I deleted exactly that file : `"/etc/squid/acls/restricted"`